# How to find reports with different access rights for same role

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

My problem is the following : I try to see which users have access to a report with which right but do not have access to another report with the same rights. I use SQL Server and I'd rather not use temporary tables.

The table roles_definition is structured the following way :

```
Role#, ReportName, AccessRight
```

Hence I want to see that if role, let's say, Administrator has access to report A with write access but does not have access to report B with the same right. I want it either to display

```
 Administrator, Report A, Write
```

or

```
 Administrator, Report B, Write
```

I have tried the following query without success.

```
SELECT 
    rd1.roleID, rd1.reportName, rd1.accessRight
FROM 
    roles_definition rd1
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    roles_definition rd2 ON rd1.roleID = rd2 .roleID
                         AND rd1.reportName <> rd2.reportName
WHERE 
    rd1.reportName IN ('Clients', 'Attachments')
ORDER BY 
    rd1.roleID, rd1.reportName;
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Are you trying to compare access rights from two tables only, i.e. find those users who have access to one of the two tables but not the same access to the other of the two tables?

Comment: Can you please add sample data and expected result preferably via sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT rd1.roleID, rd1.reportName, rd1.accessRight
FROM roles_definition rd1
  INNER JOIN roles_definition rd2
  ON rd1.roleID = rd2 .roleID
        AND rd1.reportName > rd2.reportName
        AND rd1.accessRight != rd2.accessRight
WHERE rd1.reportName IN ('Clients', 'Attachments')
ORDER BY rd1.roleID , rd1.reportName;
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `rd1.accessRight <> rd2.accessRight`? You wrote a `!` instead of `<>`

Comment: :) Anyway, big +1 on using `>` to avoid duplicates - pretty neat!